# How to use fill down specifying the number of rows I want to fill in powerquery?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

So I want to use the function "fill down" in my table in PowerQuery, but I want to specify the "step" (i want to fill down 6 times) of it.

I want to set this step because later I gonna use the FillUp function.

For example:

| Client | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 48,40 |
|  | 49,5 |
|  | 91,6 |
|  | 654,2 |
|  | 984 |
|  | 122 |
|  | 874,1 |
|  | 12,64 |
|  | 25,64 |
| B | 51,874 |
|  | 94,36 |
|  | 41,19 |
|  | 57,61 |
|  | 39,41 |
|  | 649,15 |
|  | 164,13 |
|  | 210 |
|  | 9,128 |
| C | 65,216 |

**My desirable output (after fill down):**

| Client | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 48,40 |
| A | 49,5 (fill down 1) |
| A | 91,6 (fill down 2) |
| A | 654,2 (fill down 3) |
| A | 984 (fill down 4) |
| A | 122 (fill down 5) |
| A | 874,1 (fill down 6) |
|  | 12,64 |
|  | 25,64 |
| B | 51,874 |
| B | 94,36 (fill down 1) |
| B | 41,19 (fill down 2) |
| B | 57,61 (fill down 3) |
| B | 39,41 (fill down 4) |
| B | 649,15 (fill down 5) |
| B | 164,13 (fill down 6) |
|  | 210 |
|  | 9,128 |
| C | 65,216 |

**My final output (after fill up):

| Client | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 48,40 |
| A | 49,5 |
| A | 91,6 |
| A | 654,2 |
| A | 984 |
| A | 122 |
| A | 874,1 |
| B | 12,64 (fill up) |
| B | 25,64 (fill up) |
| B | 51,874 |
| B | 94,36 |
| B | 41,19 |
| B | 57,61 |
| B | 39,41 |
| B | 649,15 |
| B | 164,13 |
| C | 210 (fill up) |
| C | 9,128 (fill up) |
| C | 65,216 |

I tried a couple of solutions, without success, I would really appreciate if somebody could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way

Add index. Number.Mod that index to get repeating groups. Add column to check for null and index <7, if so leave null, else put in placeholder. Fill. Replace placeholder with null and fill other direction.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
ModIndex = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.Mod(_, 9), Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(ModIndex, "NewClient", each if [Client]<>null then [Client] else if [Client]=null and [Index]<7 then null else "skip"),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"NewClient"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Filled Down","skip",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"NewClient"}),
#"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Replaced Value",{"NewClient"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Up",{"Client", "Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]